# Ansible get_url fails to download a protected by basic auth

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to download a protected file using HTTP from a remote server with the get_url module but the username password does not seem to get passed in the request and the task therefore fails.

I'm using Ansible 1.9.2

Here is the get_url definition I'm using:

```
- name: Downloading Artifact
  get_url:  
    url: "http://myserver/somefile.tar.gz" 
    dest: "/home/jdoe/somefile.tar.gz"
    url_username: "jdoe"
    url_password: "mysecret"
    mode: 0600
```

Here is the error I get:

```
failed: [myserver] => {"dest": "/home/jdoe/somefile.tar.gz", "failed": true,
"response": "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden", "state": "absent", 
"status_code": 403, "url": "http://myserver/somefile.tar.gz"}
msg: Request failed
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Now, I tried to download the file using cURL and it works.

Any help is appreciated as I've struggling with this for 2 days.

Comment: What happens if you log into the server you're running this playbook against, as the user you're running as, and run the following: `curl -u jdoe:mysecret -o /home/jdoe/somefile.tar.gz http://myserver/somefile.tar.gz` ? That should effectively duplicate the command you're trying to run, and might point to a permissions issue on the host.

Comment: Can you update your Ansible to 2.0 development branch and try if adding parameter `force_basic_auth=yes` helps?

Comment: Doing curl on the hosts directly works and downloads the file correctly.  I also tried running curl from within the playbook and it works as expected.  It's the get_url command that doesn't seem to work.  I haven't tried upgrading ansible to 2.0 but I'll try that.

Comment: Please provide equivalent curl command. I will try if it's module bug

Comment: Have you tried running the role/playbook in verbose mode? add "-vvvv" at the end of the command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [uri](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html) module:

```
---                                             

- hosts: hostname                                

  tasks:                                        

  - name: "download file"                       
    uri:                                        
      url: "http://somedomain.com/file.json"    
      method: GET                               
      user: "{{ somedomain.user }}"            
      password: "{{ somedomain.password }}"    
      force_basic_auth: yes                    
      dest: /tmp/somedomain.file.json           
      return_content: yes
```

If this doesn't work, probably it will have something to do with the httplib2 library version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your server does not return 401 status so that the httplib2 library can send over the BASIC authentication credentials afterwards. The solution is to upgrade to ansible >= 2.0 and use force_basic_auth: True so that the BASIC authentication credentials from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in ansible 2.9.
Turns out curl was also getting HTTP 403 but showing content anyway. GET_URL module is just more strict.

For me, the issue was solved by switching from the default Apache welcome page to the smth custom made.